# Convert KeyValuePairs<String:String> to JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to convert the `KeyValuePairs<String:String>` to JSON, here's what I have tried so far and it fails as the KeyValuePairs.

```
var userKeyValuePair: KeyValuePairs<String, String> {
    return ["FirstName": "NSDumb",
            "Address": "some address value",
            "Age": "30"]
}
```

I am using `KeyValuePairs` as I need the order of the key-value in a sequence and not unordered so i tried to convert the above to JSON using the following code

```
let serializedData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userKeyValuePair, options: [])
        let encodedData = String(data: serializedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

But the above code throws a runtime error and complains about the JSON value being invalid.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'
```

If I use a dictionary above to serialize the JSONObject it works fine but not with KeyValuePairs, I first thought maybe I should create my own type implementing the `Sequence` protocol but before I go that route I wanted to know if there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: Ultimately you need a dictionary. Of course that means there is no order. But it doesn’t matter. Any implementation that depends on the keys of a dictionary being in a specific order is broken.

Comment: yes true but right now what i am doing is before creating a custom type I am doing something like this var userDict: [Int:[String:String]]{
        return [1:["FirstName":"Username"], 2:["Age":"20"], 3:["Address":"testaddr"]]
    }

and then maybe I will sort the dictionary by keys and just get the values as per the key maybe I am still working on it and in theory it should work but i was looking for swift to handle this than me doing this or if there's a better way to do this

Comment: I did try to do what i added above but it seems like the sorted function returns an array here not a dictionary, i tried couple of other things like maps but everytime it gave an array type in return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to spin my head around it but was not able to find a way to get the `KeyValuePairs<String, String>` converted to a dictionary so i ended up using a dictionary and changed my code flow to achieve what i am trying to do.

If your requirement needs you to have a ordered dictionary then I did come across a [good library which you may want to have a look at](https://github.com/lukaskubanek/OrderedDictionary/) but in the end I used dictionary to get my work done.

When i think about it, there won't be any cases when you would need the dictionary to be ordered because the entire idea of a dictionary is to just store hashable set of key value pairs, so in the end i tweaked my logic to work around the situation and achieved the desired result.

Comment: "When i think about it, there won't be any cases when you would need the dictionary to be ordered because the entire idea of a dictionary"

99.9% of the time this is true. The only time I have needed it to be ordered is if the a 3rd party api requests their params to be ordered (which is bad on their part)

Comment: @grantespo I agree, and to be honest let me share something, there was this third party payment API which needed the dictionary to be ordered it was a real pain to implement that.

Comment: let me guess! Authorize.net :p

The only way I found to bypass that was to send the entire json request as a string lol

Comment: you are a mind reader @grantespo yes it was Authorize.net

Comment: what library you used to achieve this . i also have a same problem .@NSDumb

Comment: @BugHunterZoro Hey the link you shared is not available.I am also facing the same issue. please help. kindly respond

Comment: @Bella I have updated the link and adding the same in the comment as well for future reference 
https://github.com/lukaskubanek/OrderedDictionary/

Comment: @BugHunterZoro Hey can you please give a small snippet about the usage? Please